# HTTPS SSL error while installing android

Tags: android, ssl, openssl

I downloaded Android SDK when I run setup, it displays the following error message.

> Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml, reason: HTTPS SSL error. You might want to force download through HTTP in the settings.

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hint is in the message: use HTTP instead of HTTPS.

The [documentation says to do this as follows](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/sdk/adding-components.html#troubleshooting):

> 1. With the Android SDK and AVD Manager window open, select "Settings" in the left pane.
> 2. On the right, in the "Misc" section, check the checkbox labeled "Force https://... sources to be fetched using http://..."
> 3. Click **Save & Apply**.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the checkbox is under

Tools-> Options ...
  [x] Force https://... source sot be fetched using http://...